# Deleting a folder - it appears to think everything is individually shared (are actually junction points)

Tags: file-management, windows-server-2008

I have a strange issue deleting two TEMP user profiles on a server.

I have full ownership of all the files, but every single folder in the hierarchy seems to think it is individually shared, so I get thousands of messages about deleting them.

[image: Screenshot of all folders appearing shared]
[image: Screenshot of error]

The right-click sharing properties dialog claims that none of these folders are shared.

## Update

These appear to be junction-points, not shared folders, probably created as part of an MDT imaging process.

Here's what I get when I run the SysInternals `junction` against the path:

Junction v1.06 - Windows junction creator and reparse point viewer
    Copyright (C) 2000-2010 Mark Russinovich
    Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

```
\\?\C:\Users\TEMP.000\AppData\Local\Temp\IMGMGR_CAP_STD_64_CAP_64DDrive_k5crwkqq.bkz\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\Alphabet.xml: UNKNOWN MICROSOFT REPARSE POINT
\\?\C:\Users\TEMP.000\AppData\Local\Temp\IMGMGR_CAP_STD_64_CAP_64DDrive_k5crwkqq.bkz\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\Content.xml: UNKNOWN MICROSOFT REPARSE POINT
\\?\C:\Users\TEMP.000\AppData\Local\Temp\IMGMGR_CAP_STD_64_CAP_64DDrive_k5crwkqq.bkz\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\ConvertInkStore.exe: UNKNOWN MICROSOFT REPARSE POINT
\\?\C:\Users\TEMP.000\AppData\Local\Temp\IMGMGR_CAP_STD_64_CAP_64DDrive_k5crwkqq.bkz\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\FlickAnimation.avi: UNKNOWN MICROSOFT REPARSE POINT
\\?\C:\Users\TEMP.000\AppData\Local\Temp\IMGMGR_CAP_STD_64_CAP_64DDrive_k5crwkqq.bkz\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\FlickLearningWizard.exe: UNKNOWN MICROSOFT REPARSE POINT
\\?\C:\Users\TEMP.000\AppData\Local\Temp\IMGMGR_CAP_STD_64_CAP_64DDrive_k5crwkqq.bkz\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\hwrcommonlm.dat: UNKNOWN MICROSOFT REPARSE POINT
```

Comment: Further digging indicates these may actually be junction points (symbolic links)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that all these junction points were invalid, as all the files appeared empty when opened and `Junction` reported `UNKNOWN MICROSOFT REPARSE POINT` for all of them.

I've managed to delete them by using the following command from the base-directory of the problem, in this case `C:\Users\TEMP.000\`

```
del /s /al /f /q *.*
```

Once I had done that, I could delete all the folders as usual.

Comment: Windows Server 2008, as tagged.